# nodeaccess configuration problems

Tags: users

I created a view that I called gallery (in Drupal 7) which links to a number of sub galleries (http://quaaoutlodge.com/gallery). The sub galleries are of content type gallery. 
So, I installed the nodeaccess module because the galleries and the gallery main page should only be accessible by my GalleryViewer  (and GalleryEditor) so I set the Gallery node type up accordingly (no checks for anonymous user). I saved grants and rebuilt permissions. Now, even tho I did the above, any user caan browse my gallery types that are linked from http://quaaoutlodge.com/gallery. Why is this? What am I doing wrong? :o

Comment: I think you have to set the permission inside the Views `BLOCK SETTINGS > Access`

Comment: @ninjascorner Thanks! That did it for my gallery view, yes! Thank you, copy and paste this answer to answers and you get your check mark... even tho it didn't really address my node access issue - do you also know how I resolve that by any chance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the permission inside the Views BLOCK SETTINGS > Access